# Counting words, and ordering strings that have that N word

Tags: python, nlp, counting

I have and entry like this:

```
(bc9, de, viana=do=castelo)
(bc9, tomar o, aeroporto=de=pedras=rubras)
(arábia=saudita, em o, afeganistão)
```

And I want to count how many times and which appears the most, like this:

```
bc9: 2 times. 

(bc9, de, viana=do=castelo)
(bc9, tomar o, aeroporto=de=pedras=rubras)

afeganistão: 1 times. 

(arábia=saudita, em o, afeganistão)
```

The words between the commas aren't supposed to be counted, either.
Here is the code, it output some connectors, that I'll remove, but after that, i thought of iterating the input and grouping the sentences that contains the words in order in their appear

```
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
import operator

Tk().withdraw() 
filename = askopenfilename() 
file = open(filename, "r+")
wordcount = {}
saida=open('saida.txt','w')
string = 'portugal] <civ> <*> prop m s @p<   ['
for line in file:
 line = line.replace("(", "")
 line = line.replace(")", "")
 line = line.replace(",", "")
 line = line.replace("=", " ")
 line = line.replace(string, "")
 saida.write(line)
saida.close()
file.close()
file=open("saida.txt","r")
for word in file.read().split():
 if word not in wordcount:
    wordcount[word] = 1
 else:
    wordcount[word] += 1
file.close
sorted_x = sorted(wordcount.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
saida2=open('saida2.txt','w')
for key, value in sorted_x:
 saida2.write(key+':')
 saida2.write('\t')
 saida2.write(str(value) + '\n')
 print key, value
```

Comment: Good for you. What have your tried so far? Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: sorry, I've already counted the words, and stored them in a OrderedDict, but i'm having troubles to iterate over my input file

Comment: Then please post your code, along with a specific question about where you are having problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter 

zipped_entries = zip(*entries)
Counter(zipped_entries[0] + zipped_entries[2])
```

Assumes you have a fixed number of entries (3). Should be enough code to get you started.

Comment: actually discovered that my problem is reading it, I need to read it from ( until the first comma, and from the second comma until ), any tips?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're looking for. Maybe open a new question with specific examples of what you want, what you've tried, and how it fails.